# ASP.Net server control for modal popup using Telerik Ajax and need to disable browser window scrolling

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, telerik

I have a ASP.Net server control for modal popup and the page is using Telerik Ajax. When the window is popped up, if you use the mouse wheel the browser window keeps on scrolling and I want to disable that.

I tried to execute the javascript to just show an alert from the server control like below and nothing happens(really I wanted to use the commented line just after to disable browser window scrolling). The server control code is executed on postback(not on initial page load). Not sure what else need to be done

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPreRender(e);
            //register javascript here if needed
            AddScript();

        }

        private void AddScript()
        {
            ClientScriptManager csm = this.Page.ClientScript;
            string scriptblock = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('hi');</script>";
            //string scriptblock = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">$(\"body\").css(\"overflow\", \"hidden\");</script>";

            string scriptname = "DisableBrowserScrollBar()";

            Type csType = this.GetType();
            if (!csm.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(csType, scriptname))
            {
                csm.RegisterClientScriptBlock(csType, scriptname, scriptblock, false);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a ScriptManager on your page? If so, you need to do this:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, csType, scriptName, scriptblock, true);
```

Comment: Please note that I am trying to do this from a server control, where I do not have a reference to RadScriptManager. If I do the same (call the AddScript()) from my page template base class, which all the pages inherits from things work fine.

Comment: I contacted Telerik Support and they mentioned it is an issue due to telerik AJAX controls and I need to inject the script using RadScriptManager reference to master page in the page base template (not from the server controls).